# Table View is taking interaction when a view of same bounds is added above that in OS X

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, operating-system

My app contains a Table View which is scrolling and taking events properly. But after that I have to show a custom pop up to screen for that I have added a full view over the Table View. But after adding the view over Table View, Table view is still scrolling and taking events.

Please help if anyone have knowledge about that...

Thanks

Comment: it means you need one Transparent view -- add your custom pop up screen

Comment: Can you give us some code?

Comment: It is simple a view from a nib over a simple table view.

Comment: Yes, I need a transparent view, But does not want to interact with previous view

Comment: The easiest way is `[tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` when you show pop up and turn it on when pop up dismiss

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to add a blur view into your nib file first. This is better approach as the user is made aware of the current enabled object.

Once you add the blur view over the tableView you are showing, add your custom pop-over. This would maintain a clear demarcation between the two views and you would be able to achieve the functionality you want as the touches won't flow to your tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps may work:

- Add overlay view on screen to show data on top of table view
- make TableView Disbaled as soon as u add view on it.